# Git rebase branch onto squash merge

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history, git-squash

I did a mess with my features branches. What I had:

```
master:  A - B
               \
branch1:        E - F
                     \
branch2:              G - H
```

And then

- I squashed and merge *branch1* to the *main*
- Added a few commits on the *main*
- Rebase my *branch2* on the *main*

```
master:  A - B - EF - I - J
                           \      
branch2:                    E - F - G - H
```

Is there a fast way to clean my *branch2*, and find the commits that exist there, without the commits from *branch1*?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to interactively rebase the last 4 commits on branch2,
and deleting the two branch1 commits from the "todo" list:

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase -i --no-ff HEAD~4
```

In the editor remove the 2 commits from branch1, then save and close the editor.

In case the editor appearing is `vi` and you're not familiar with it:

- Press the [Esc] key to make sure you're not in insert mode
- Use the arrow keys to move the cursor to a line you want to delete
- Type `dd` on the keyboard to delete a line.
- When you're done deleting lines, type this to save and quit: `:wq`